# It's hard to find the groups cohomology of $Sl_2 (F_p $),where $F_p $ is the field with $p $ elements?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, group-cohomology

It's hard to find the groups cohomology of $Sl_2 (F_p $),where $F_p $ is the field with $p $ elements? I need some references about this subject. Why it's useful to know it?